# My WT stamp on my passport is expiring the same day I enter the US. I have a valid ESTA though. What does this mean?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, us-visa-waiver-program, passport-stamps

I have an ESTA valid until 2018 and I am flying to the USA this Wednesday the 25th of January. My WT stamp in my passport is valid from Oct 28 2016 to Jan 25 2017. I haven't been in the USA since Nov 1st 2016.

Will there be any issues for me entering the USA this Wednesday the 25th? Or do they just re-stamp it and start a fresh 90 days?

I was only in the USA a total of 5 days on my last 90 day WT stamp.

Answer (score 8):

Because you left the US, that entry stamp is no longer relevant - you will (usually) be issued a new one on arrival.

If you don't get a stamp (which may happen if you use an APC kiosk, which is likely), assume you got the default 90 days. Or, to be dead certain, [you can look up your admission record online](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/recent-search)

Do note that the admission period remains active if you go to Canada or Mexico for a short visit. It's a system designed to prevent visa runs.

Comment: Thank you! That was super helpful. Based on what you said I think I should be ok. Phew!

Comment: @Sabina Just to clarify: did you exit the US by air? If so, you'll  be 100% fine

Comment: @Sabina Also, if this answers your question, please accept it by clicking the button below the down arrow

Comment: @Sabina even if you exited by land or sea you will be fine, though there may be some administrative hassle if your exit wasn't recorded.

Comment: @phoog Correct, I was going to advise her to check her I-94 if having exited by land, and if the exit's not there, send evidence to the address in Ohio